# Xcode Interface-builder and Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

When we add objects like background imageViews in Interface-builder and donot make outlets, does they use any memory and leak when we release all outlets and these views were not release?

Comment: they are created in `autorelease`d way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't cause any memory leaks... They are autoreleased objects